# Motivo para fechamento "Esta pergunta pertence a outro site da rede Stack Exchange" foi removido ou não existe no META?

Tags: suporte

Tentei votar para fechar recentemente uma pergunta que pertencia ao SOpt (técnica), mas na hora de escolher o motivo de fechamento, não constava a opção mencionada:

Passo 1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Passo 2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No SOpt, temos a opção mencionada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- É um bug?
- Ou foi intencionalmente removida?
- Ou essa opção nunca existiu no META?

Não sei qual pergunta fazer ao certo pois quase não (ou nunca) votei para fechar perguntas aqui no META, então não lembro se menu está correto.

Comment: Note antes de tudo que tem uma orientação na rede que é "não migre porcaria". A migração ou sugestão dela só deve ser usada em caso de perguntas **bem formuladas** e já em condição de receber respostas no site destino. O post original sobre migração é esse: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/ - dependendo do post que for, a restrição pode até ter sido causada por alguma tag usada.

Comment: Migrações à parte, ainda sim acho que falta ter um motivo "não pertence ao meta"  (o equivalente a  "totalmente off")